# Excel offers different options for markers in different runs - why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, default-settings

When I look at the built-in marker options in Excel, on of my running sessions offers cross as an option, another one does not.
What could be causing this and how to fix this easily?

Using Excel 2016.

**Screenshots**

See the left side especially, the graphs themselves are not important, left them in for completeness.

*When cross marker is offered*

[image]

*When it is not*

[image]

---

*I have tried searching online, but all the resources are pointing out how to change the marker type - I know how to do that, I don't know why I am offered different markers to choose from in two sessions.*

Comment: do both files have them same extension?

Comment: Yes, it happens witthin the same file. (When I create two charts within same file.)

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Yepp, added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross is present in both cases.

In the first case, the border of the marker is red, and the fill is either white or blank, so you can see the cross, the X, and the star.

In the second case, the border of the marker is red, and the fill color is also red. So the cross, the X, and the star all look like large red squares.

Change the fill color, preferably to none, and you will see the markers more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

What version of excel do you use?

The series markers for charts with multiple series in Excel 2013 all default to the same marker.

However, in Excel 2010, each series is assigned a different tag style by default.

If you need them to be consistent, you can change it manually:

Double click the series to open the format pane. In the format pane, select the paint bucket icon to go to the color and fill section. Here, click "Marker" to reveal the options for series markers.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I got to this point. The problem is that in some cases the cross is there among the choices I can select from, in some cases it is not.